# how to hide data from frontend in angular

Tags: angular

I have an angular 5 app from which I want to make an http request which will hit a URL in following format:

> https://example.com/api?email=***{{myemail@gmail.com}}***&pass=***{{my
>   password}}***&input={{user input}}

which will give me an json response.

The form will only have one input box, where user will fill the 'user input'.
Apart from that I need to send an hard-coded email and password which I can't keep in client for security purpose.

Any suggestion how can I hide it.

Answer (score 0):

First you do not want to submit these values as url parameters, as then they are exposed in the address bar:

```
https://example.com/api?email={{myemail@gmail.com}}&pass={{my password}}&input={{user input}}
```

Instead make a POST or PATCH to a specific endpoint like this:

```
https://example.com/api/user
```

and include your data in a JSON body, something like:

```
{
"email":"mickey@disney.com",
"pass":"whatever"
"input":"user data"
}

putUserData(body: any){
    const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    const url = 'https://example.com/api/user';
    return this._http.patch(url, body, options)
       .map((response: Response) => response.json())
}
```

Before you call this endpoint, first call another endpoint to get the hardcoded email and password, for example:

GET https://example.com/api/user/credentials

This should provide a JSON response that contains that data:

```
{
"email":"mickey@disney.com",
"pass":"whatever"
}
```

And when the user submits the form, you can merge this object with the form object. This way you are not hard-coding this data on the client nor storing it anywhere on the client.

**But this is still not a secure solution since you are passing credentials which would be quite easy for a hacker to get hold if they were determined enough.**